# Is it possible to use custom error pages with MVC site but not Web API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, web-config

I have an MVC project with a /api folder which contains my Web API controllers. I want the following things:

- My MVC site to serve a custom error page when an error occurs
- My Web API to serve the default error response (json/xml containing exception and stack trace)

In the web.config for my MVC site, I have an httpErrors node, and have set the errorMode to "Custom" so that I can have nice error pages when 404s/500s/etc. occur during browsing of the MVC site:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error prefixLanguageFilePath="" statusCode="404" path="Content\notfound.htm" responseMode="File" />
  <error statusCode="500" path="/Errors" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  <error statusCode="403" path="/Errors/Http403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" /></httpErrors>
```

With that configuration however, the API will serve the custom error page when an error occurs, not json/xml with the exception/stack trace (which is the desired behavior).

Is there a way to configure custom errors to only apply to my MVC site and not the Web API? This blog says there is not (http://blog.kristandyson.com/2012/11/iis-httperrors-aspnet-web-api-fully.html), but I'd like to hear if anyone else has found a work around since that blog was published.

I suppose if there is not I could create a separate project/assembly for my Web API project. That would allow me to configure httpErrors for MVC and Web API separately, but I would prefer not to create another project just so I have yet another web.config to configure.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Well, after a nearly a year of letting this question marinade, I gave it another shot. Here's the web.config magic that got me what I wanted:

```
<!-- inside of <configuration> to allow error
    responses from requests to /api through -->
<location path="api">
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" >
        <clear/>
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</location>

<!-- original httpErrors, inside of <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
 to serve custom error pages when the MVC site returns an error code -->
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="400" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="400" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="Content\notfound.htm" responseMode="File"/>
      <error prefixLanguageFilePath="" statusCode="404" path="Content\notfound.htm" responseMode="File" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/errors" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="403" path="/errors/http403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

The crux of what's going on here is that the `<location>` node allows you to override settings made at a less specific path. So while we have errorMode="Custom" for path=".", we override that for the our Web API's path with the `<location path="api">` node, and the httpErrors configuration within it.

I had seen  nodes before, but it didn't dawn on me that this was their purpose until now. This article goes into more detail on the configuration inheritance model of IIS/.NET, which I found very informative: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - I've been banging my head against the wall trying to work this out and just didn't think about this nice simple solution!

Comment: It works for me only on `IIS Express` on my local machine. Have you tried to run it on IIS 8 for example? Does it works? IIS 8+ seems to ignore <location path="api"> overrided configuration.

Comment: This worked for me in IIS 7.5. Thank you for this solution!

Comment: This was finally the solution that allowed for everything to work as needed.

Comment: Did anyone try this with attribute routing? It just can't seem to work for my project. My ApiControllers are placed under `Controllers\Api`, and I have this in my web.config:
```
<location path="~/Controllers/Api">
    <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough" >
        <clear/>
      </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Wow why did it take so long for me to find a simple solution rather than a huge re-write of error handling so many others were suggesting...

Comment: In my case, I had to remove the line <clear/> to make it work

Comment: GOD DAMN THANK YOU!!!! ive been struggling with this for over 3 days now you sir are a life saver

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this, but how about writing the code to handle your MVC application errors, like shown here [http://thirteendaysaweek.com/2012/09/25/custom-error-page-with-asp-net-mvc-4](http://thirteendaysaweek.com/2012/09/25/custom-error-page-with-asp-net-mvc-4/)/ ?

His code show that he is doing this at the application level (Global.asax), but I guess you could just as well trap exceptions at a lower level in the same way, with one method for MVC and another one for Web API.

Comment: Handling MVC application errors is not what I am looking to do, and not what this question is about. I want to be able to return an error code from my Web API (e.g. 400 when a client has made a request to the API incorrectly) and not have .NET redirect to a custom error page. Conversely, when a 404/500/etc occurs on my MVC site (in which the Web API is hosted), I want to serve the custom error page. I want both of these behaviors at the same time, with MVC/Web API hosted in the same site. The solution is in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

What have worked for me:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="Redirect" errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="Redirect" path="<!--path here-->" />
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="Redirect" path="<!--path here-->" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="Redirect" path="<!--path here-->" />
</httpErrors>
```

Seems like just setting existingResponse="Auto" will do the job.