# Specifying relative path in web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

We encountered a problem after deploying our MVC3 Asp.net application to a client's site.
In the client site, a virtual directory has been created in IIS7 to which we need to deploy.

The problem is in *web.config* where we have specified a custom error page as

```xml
<!-- Custom Error Pages -->
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Http403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

The error page paths are not working properly. After an investigation, we found that I have to specify the virtual directory and set the path to `/virtual_directory/Error/Http404`

Is there a way I can specify the path relative to the virtual directory?

Comment: I would have said to try `path="~/Error/Http404"`but I'm afraid it won't work : http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors/error "If you choose the ExecuteURL response mode, the path has to be a server relative URL (for example, /404.htm)"

Answer (score 1):

If the virtual directory path is constant in your deployment environments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12746689/241211) might serve your purposes, with different *web.config* and *web.release.config* files.

If the virtual directory path can vary, the original questioner [says it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296237/is-it-possible-to-use-a-relative-path-when-setting-a-custom-error-page-in-iis7#comment15193588_6296237).